# Undefined index php will it still display at other users when we modify the php_ini setting?

Tags: php, php-ini

So I am a beginner in php and I was reading through a lot of posts suggesting how to remove the undefined index problem in php.

Mostly there are two methods

1. change the setting in php_ini
2. have an `isset()` condition.

So if I choose method 1 and uploaded my website to the server,when other users click on it,will the UNDEFINED INDEX warning shows up ?

I mean since we are only changing our own setting so it will still display when others click on it right ? Really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: 1 is not fixing the problem - it's ignoring it.

Comment: Where did you change php settings? Did you restart server after modification settings on server?

Comment: If by "change ini setting" you're referring to **hiding errors**: that's the wrong way to do it! Never hide errors, they are trying to tell you something! Read [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).